# SequenceInputStream is not taking enumeration argument

Tags: java

I am new to java technology.So i was going through SequenceInputStreamI tried below code,but i am not able to find the exact problem, kindly some one help

```
public class SequenceInput {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Enumeration e=new MyEnum();
    SequenceInputStream sin=new SequenceInputStream(e);
    DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(sin);

    String s="";
    while(null !=s) {
        s=din.readLine();

        if(null !=s) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    din.close();
//      new Vector().elements();




}


//Enumeration Class

public class MyEnum implements Enumeration{

    InputStream in[];
    int i=0;

    public  MyEnum(){
    try {
        in=new InputStream[] {new FileInputStream("src/a1.txt"),new FileInputStream("src/a2.txt"),new FileInputStream("src/a3.txt"),new FileInputStream("src/a4.txt")};
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }


}

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        if(in.length<=4) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nextElement() {

        return in[i++];
    }



}
}
```

In this line `Enumeration e=new MyEnum()`; it is showing 
- No enclosing instance of type `SequenceInput` is accessible. Must qualify the 
     allocation with an enclosing instance of type `SequenceInput` (e.g. `x.new A()` where `x` is an 
     instance of `SequenceInput`).

I am not getting the exact problem.

Else i have used `new Vector().add()` and it was working fine with `sequenceInputStream`. Wanted to know about above code..Where am i making mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To access your class without needed an enclosing instance, you have to make it `static`

```
public static class MyEnum implements Enumeration {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class SequenceInput {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Enumeration e=new MyEnum();
    SequenceInputStream sin=new SequenceInputStream(e);
    DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(sin);

    String s="";
    while(null !=s) {
        s=din.readLine();

        if(null !=s) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    din.close();
//      new Vector().elements();




}


//Enumeration Class

public static class MyEnum implements Enumeration{

    InputStream in[];
    int i=0;

    public  MyEnum(){
    try {
        in=new InputStream[] {new FileInputStream("src/a1.txt"),new FileInputStream("src/a2.txt"),new FileInputStream("src/a3.txt"),new FileInputStream("src/a4.txt")};
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }


}

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        if(in.length<=4) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nextElement() {

        return in[i++];
    }



}
}
```